# How to make form model update on blur in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is there an equivalent to this in angular 2?

```
ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

In Angular 2 you can use the native DOM events

```
<input (blur)="someMethod()" />
```

Now, just define a method that does what you need when the field is blurred

Comment: but I'd like to just do a two way data binding on an input. If I have to implement a method it adds more overhead to implementing a two way binding.

Comment: @matthewdaniel, not sure what you are asking. If you want out-of-the-box 2-way data binding use `[(ngModel)]` if you want to define a blur handler use TGH's approach. If you want to tell `ngModel` to only update on blur,...well actually I'd like to know that also. I don't believe there is currently a way to do that...easily

Comment: The Vue.js equivalent is the "lazy" binding modifier: v-model.lazy="myData". This would be great to see in Angular 2.

Comment: I had to add `tabindex="0"` to the `<input/>` to get it to work.

Answer (score 19):

Even though this is a very old thread, there is now a very neat solution which comes with Angular5.

You trigger the update on blur like this:

**Tempalte driven forms:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="lastname" [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }">
```

**Reactive forms:**

```
this.nameForm = new FormGroup ({
  firstname: new FormControl('', {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'submit'
  }),
  lastname: new FormControl('', {
    validators: Validators.required,
    updateOn: 'submit'
  })
});
```

(you can select `submit` or `blur` as values)

Reference:
https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-5-forms-update-9587c3735cd3