# Allow only one decimal on input in Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

This is my input:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="minimumRange" min="1" placeholder="0.0" step="0.1" type="number">
```

What I need is, when someone enters

> "1"

, I need it to return

> "1.0".

on blur 
 How is this possible?

Comment: Use `@Pipe`. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456114/angular-2-pipe-limit-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: @SrAxi, please post an example, thanks,.

Comment: is the type of `minimumRange` a string or a number ?

Comment: the type of minimumRange is : number

Comment: you need to output 1.0 because of style or because of some processing on the server or elsewhere that requires a number with 1 decimal ? Because the number representation of `"1.0"` is `1`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the **number** `@Pipe` you should be able to achieve this.

```
<input [ngModel]="minimumRange | number : '1.1-2'" min="1" (ngModelChange)="minimumRange=$event" placeholder="0.0" step="0.1" type="number">
```

For more info:

- [What are the parameters for the number Pipe - Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477970/what-are-the-parameters-for-the-number-pipe-angular-2)
- http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-decimal-pipe-percent-pipe-and-currency-pipe-example

Hope it helped! Good coding bro!

**Update:**

If we use @Pipe in model like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="myModel| uppercase">
```

It will throw the following error:

> Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column X

We will just need to change it to this:

```
<input [ngModel]="myModel| uppercase" (ngModelChange)="myModel=$event">
```

**Update2:**

Added `(ngModelChange)="minimumRange=$event"` to keep the two way binding functionality.

As @n00dle pointed me, removing the `()` removes the 2 way binding functionality. So the way to use `@Pipe` in a 2-way-binding would be using also `(ngModelChange)`.

This could be of huge use:

- [Using Pipes within ngModel on INPUT Elements in Angular2-View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular2-view)

Comment: I'm receiving template errors when I apply pipe mate.. that's why I asked.

Comment: pipes are not allowed in 2-way data-binding.

Comment: may i know where it is mentioned please `pipes are not allowed in 2-way data-binding`?  @n00dl3

Comment: @n00dl3 Are allowed. Not allowed in `action expression`, but if we just change `[(ngModel)]` to `[ngModel]` it lets us apply the `@Pipe`.

Comment: 2-way data binding is a combination of a binding and an action expression... So it is not allowed in 2-way data-binding, Period. @SrAxi If you knew it, why do you write it ?

Comment: @n00dl3 You can make it work as it shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39642882/using-pipes-within-ngmodel-on-input-elements-in-angular2-view

Comment: @n00dl3 I always preffer to use built in methods, if Angular offers us a built in `@Pipe` why not use it? I preffer to change slightly my 2-way-binding behaviour rather than having to 'manually' convert the value in each component where I want this to happen. But, I am just learning, if you have a better way to do this please post an answer and tag me, so I can learn it and use it on my project. Thanks for the chat! :D

Comment: I never said you should not use it, I just pointed out that your code was wrong. When I said "two-way data-binding" I meant "banana in a box". But nevermind you changed, that's fine.

Comment: @n00dl3 You did well pointing it out. My first answer wasn't correct nor precise, thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks guys, how can I change this on blur, not on any event, like above?

Comment: @eric.dummy No problem mate! ;) I honestly don't understand your question but the OP (original post) has been answered I believe. You could choose the correct answer for the current question and make a new one with detailed information about this new question that you have, and we will be all glad to give you a hand. Is just to have a question/answer for each issue and avoid extending a question until it loses its original intention. Looking forward to hearing from you! ;)

Comment: Oh, it's not extending, I'm only asking how to make the (ngModelChange) act on blur not on $event :) That was meant in original question...

Comment: @eric.dummy Oh! Ok! Now I understand! I think `(blur)` should make the deal here. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33966050/how-to-make-form-model-update-on-blur-in-angular-2

Comment: Will there still be 2 way binding this way?

Comment: @eric.dummy Yes! Maybe this example es more clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34918198/how-to-use-onblur-event-on-angular2 . With that you should be good to go! :P

Comment: **Note**: this does not behave exactly the same as regular pipe (display). Observed on angular 9.

-- Regular: `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}` vs Used with input: `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits|maxIntegerDigits}`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<input [(ngModel)]="minimumRange" min="1" placeholder="0.0" step="0.1" type="number" (keyup)='conversion()'>

conversion(){
  this.minimumRange = this.minimumRangex.toPrecision(2);
}
```

Comment: @n00dl3, please see the pipe comment. Thanks.

Comment: the issue with this is that I need to know how to put this in component. I can't place a script in HTML..

Comment: @Padeep Jain, Where does `this.minimumRangex` come from? Thanks

Comment: I believe it should be typo, there should be `this.minimumRange`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  private _minimumRange:number;

  get minimumRange():number{
    return this._minimumRange;
  }

  set minimumRange(num:number){
    this._minimumRange = num.toPrecision(2);
  }
```

```html
      <input [(ngModel)]="minimumRange" min="1" placeholder="0.0" step="0.1" type="number">
```